# setting breakpoint in pdb python

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I want to set breakpoints using pdb and then run the loop in the program until that breakpoint. and then after checking the values keep continuing (only stopping at that point) until the loop ends. how do i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your program into pdb from the command line by running

```
python -m pdb your_script.py
```

This will stop execution at line 1, now set breakpoint with `b linenumber` e.g. `b 25`. Now type `run` it will run the program until that break point.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the code, one way is to add this line where you want to break:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Comment: yes i added it. but it stops at that point one time and then when i press c it doesnt stop again (in a loop)

Comment: I want to keep looping it and stopping it at a point in a loop to check the values

Comment: use 'n' for next and 'c' for continue, or browse the pdb documentation